# Is it possible to use python.locals() with numba?

Tags: python, numba, local-variables, dynamic-variables

I'm working on a python function that dynamically creates and uses variables. When i try to speed it up with numba I get this error message:
'numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'locals': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>'

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def make_variables():
    for i in range(6, 9):
        locals()[f"my_variable_{i}"] = i
    for i in range(6, 9):
        res = locals()[f"my_variable_{i}"] + 2
        yield res

print(list(make_variables()))
```

Comment: `locals` is inherently untyped. Have you considered just using a dictionary to store your values instead?

Answer (score 0):

Solution with dictonary instead of locals()

```
import numba

@numba.njit
def dynamic_dict():
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(6, 9):
        key = f"my_key_{i}"
        value = i
        my_dict[key] = value

    for i in range(6, 9):
        yield my_dict[f"my_key_{i}"] + 2

print(list(dynamic_dict()))
```